Taylor expansion of the square of distance function.
Recently I encountered an estimate in PDE that requires information from higher-order coefficients in the Taylor series of the function mentioned in the title. The setting states as follows.
Let $U$ be a domain containing the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Such domain is equipped with a metric $g$, where
\begin{equation}
g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+o(|x|).
\end{equation}
Let $d(x)$ be the distance between $x$ and the origin, we consider the function $f(x)=(d(x))^2$. The estimate I’m dealing with requires the Taylor coefficients of (at least) order 3 at the origin.
Here’s my attempt. Consider the inverse of exponential map at the origin $\text{exp}_0^{-1}$ on the neighborhood $\text{exp}_0(B(0,\epsilon))$, where $B(0,\epsilon)$ is a small ball centered at the origin, we have
\begin{equation}
f(x)=|\text{exp}_0^{-1}(x)|^2.
\end{equation}
By the property of the metric, we can write down
\begin{equation}
f(x)=|x|^2+o(|x|^2).
\end{equation}
Then I failed to find out coefficient of any higher order terms. My problems state as follows:

Do the coefficients of cubic terms vanish?
How can I compute (explicitly) the coefficients of terms up to order 5?


See https://mathoverflow.net/a/393708/613
